# Cannot see Widget in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: c#, javascript, widget, internet-explorer-7

Im at my wits end trying to find a problem with a html/javascript page that acts like a widget that wont load in ie6 or ie7..  Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on this?

http://cdn.xas.com/SampleOutput.html

Im guessing its some problem with some of my javascript?

I am building up the html in javascript, it could also be the html thats generated from this yes?

thanks
Neil

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: if you go to that link.. you can see the widget and all the code by following the eventWidget.jss.  Its probably easier to view it like that!

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? What do you mean that it will not load?

Comment: Don't now if i'm doing it right but if you execute function `GetOffers` in console modal window is showing and working http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7417149/Screenshots/ch.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no offers displayed as `dataCollection.Offers` passed into function `core.createOffersList`, sourced from `this.eventData` in the `BoonCentral.Com.Cdn.Widget`, class is an empty array. As assigned by line 494:

```
this.eventData = {"Address":"10 Wellington Quay Jamestown, Dublin","ID":48,"LogoUrl":"http:\/\/www.booncentral.com\/VenueImages\/48\/201209171247\/0e8ed5bd-6076-4b67-a96a-5365cf225636the_workmans_club_dublin_28659.gif","Name":"The Workmans","Offers":[],"VenueProfile":"<p>&nbsp;<\/p><p>Dublin's most excellent new live music venue, situated in the heart of \u000d\u000athe city and open Monday to Sunday from 5pm til, well, when we kick you \u000d\u000aout!<\/p>"};
```

For IE6, you may be hitting this issue: http://kmleeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/document-createelement-problem-in-ie6/

Hope this helps you narrow down the problem :-).

Comment: ah sorry, the date has passed the day when the offers will show.  Ill fix this later and have some data there ..  :(

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't answer your question- Why are you trying to make it work on IE6/7 ?

IE6 & 7 are barely used and are being phased out. 
You're better off spending your time optimizing for current browsers..

According to http://www.theie7countdown.com/, the worldwide usage of IE7 is 4%.
According to http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp , it's now less than 1%.

With regards to this specific widget/project, is it taking you more than 1-4% of your time to address this issue?

Just my thoughts...

Comment: World wide use of the browsers does not matter, what matters is what browser the people who are visiting the site are using. If there are still lots of people using IE 6/7 visiting a site then it is important to ensure that the site loads correctly for those users.

Comment: this is true- except that the statistic should represent the average statistic of who's visiting your site. 

After all, the people visiting your site are part of the 'users' in general, and I find it hard to believe OP is specifically targeting IE7 users, meaning the browsers his visitors use should more or less be around that statistic

Comment: No those statistics have no correlation at all to the browser used by a specific web site as it all depends on the web sites target audience. There are web sites out there that get the majority of their traffic from older browsers such as IE 6/7 because the target audience is using older machines and do not keep up to date with the latest software and hardware. The absolute worst thing you can do when designing a site is to base it off of global stats rather then the stats from the site itself and its user base. Also its not about who he is targeting but who is using it.